# SimpleXML node casting to string not working

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to get a currency rate from this XML file:

```
http://www.bank.lv/vk/xml.xml
```

I am getting a currency ID from a HTML form, after that I have to find it according currency rate.

I am using SimpleXML and XPath, my selection is as follow:

```
$current_rate = $rates->xpath("/CRates/Currencies/Currency[ID='" .$source_currency ."']/Rate");
```

`$source_currency` is tested and valid, however, when casting `$current_rate` to `(string)`, I get the word `Array`.

Do I have a mistake in the XPath node selection or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_rate = $rates->xpath("/CRates/Currencies/Currency[ID='" .$source_currency ."']/Rate");
```

Will return an array even if just 1 result is returned, if you use `print_r` you can see what is returned:

```
print_r($current_rate);
```

To access it you will have to use:

```
if (isset($current_rate))
{
    echo $current_rate[0];
}
```

Or if there is the possibility of having more than 1 result for that given `$source_currency`:

```
foreach ($current_rate as $rate)
{
    echo $rate, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! I was just a little confused, because I looked it up, and everyone just seemed to be casting it straight to string. Thank you!